# motion_planning_msgs

Tags: ros

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I am trying to use kinematics_msgs package, which depends on motion_planning_msgs.

So I have downloaded motion_planning_msgs package and tried to compile, but when i do rosmake motion_planning_msgs, this never ends compiling.

I've seen this package has been deprecated, but if I want to use kinematics_msgs, what should I do?

Thank you in advance

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/44607/motion_planning_msgs/) by [BLaS](https://answers.ros.org/users/1491/blas/) on ROS Answers with karma: 56 on 2012-09-26

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Have a look at the "Used By" on the right hand side here and take your pick [http://ros.org/wiki/kinematics_msgs](http://ros.org/wiki/kinematics_msgs#)

---

Originally posted by [MarkyMark2012](https://answers.ros.org/users/2193/markymark2012/) with karma: 1834 on 2012-09-26

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0